# Save each row of a numpy array to a separate row of a file instead of separating it

Tags: python, save, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy array:

```
matrix = numpy.zeros([30, 30], dtype = numpy.int32)
```

I later change the values of this array and save it to a file like so:

```
conf_mat = open("conf_mat.txt", "w")
conf_mat.write(str(matrix))
```

But the result in the file looks like this

```
[[    0     0     0     8   161     0    18     0     0     0     0     0
     13     0     1     0   140     2     0     0     8     0    14     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     0    41    31     0    39     0     0     0     0     0
     44     0     0     0    21    39     0     0    39     0   105     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0]
 [    0     0     0    71   162     0   155     0     0     1     0     0
      6     0     0     0   350   110     0     0     8     0    21     0
      0     0     0     0     0     0]
 ...
```

As you can see 1 row of the matrix is separated into 3 lines in the document.
How can I write the whole row of the matrix on just one row of the file?

PS: I don't know if it makes a difference, but I am using a remote linux server via ssh connection.

Comment: Are you sure each row isn't written in one line and your text editor just wraps around long lines? Your main issue is that you do `str(matrix)` which can be a hassle to read the file back wih all the square brackets. It's best to stick to numpy.loadtxt as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save numpy arrays, use `numpy.save` (npy format) or `numpy.savetxt` (CSV/plaintext), and to load `numpy.load` or `numpy.loadtxt`, see https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/how-to-io.html and https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.io.html

`numpy.savetxt` can only store 1D or 2D arrays, though. And to store the datas as integer values instead of exponential notation, use `fmt='%d'` as a keyword argument to `numpy.savetxt`, e.g. `numpy.savetxt("foo", matrix, fmt='%d')`. For more info on the format flags, please check https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: When I try .savetxt() the values look like this 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 .... How can I make them ints?

Comment: Pass `fmt='%d'` as a keyword argument

Comment: And one more question. Can I make it so that each value takes like 5 spaces so that the data is more ordered and each value is exactly above the value of the row below? Do you understand what I am talking about?

Comment: You can use `fmt='%5d'`, to pad the number with spaces, where the `5` denotes the *minimum* width of the field. Numbers which take more space than that will still be expanded to have enough space. I added a link to the documentation of `savetxt`.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off-topic: you could also use pandas to save the numpy matrix:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([4, 2])).to_csv()
',0,1\n0,0.0,0.0\n1,0.0,0.0\n2,0.0,0.0\n3,0.0,0.0\n'
>>>
```

(if you use `to_csv(<filename>)` it will be written to disk instead)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not looking for csv format, but it could be useful for somebody else. :)